# react-router-bootstrap linkcontainer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

How do I use react-router-bootstrap to link to another react component? Do I need to set up my routes with react-router first? I don't know how to use react-router-bootstrap's LinkContainer to route a NavItem to a separate react component.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, NavDropdown, MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import request from 'superagent';
import CardList from './CardList.jsx';
import AddNewCard from './AddNewCard.jsx';
import ReactRouterBootstrap, { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';

const propTypes = {
  children: React.PropTypes.element,
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cards: [],
    }
    this.addNewCardHandler = this.addNewCardHandler.bind(this);
    this.deleteCardHandler = this.deleteCardHandler.bind(this);
    this.saveButtonHandler = this.saveButtonHandler.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getAllCards();
  }

  getAllCards() {
    const url = '/api/cards';
    request.get(url)
    .end((err,res) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(`err: ${err}`);
      }
      this.setState({
        cards: res.body,
      });
    });
  }
  deleteCardHandler(id) {
    console.log(`id: ${id}`);
  }
  addNewCardHandler() {
    request.post(url)
      .send({
        firstname,
        lastname,
        email,
        phonenumber,
        location,
        jobtitle,
        company,
        githubhandle,
        linkedinhandle,
        twitterhandler,
        personalsite,
      })
      .end((err, res) => {
        console.log(`res: ${res}`);
        console.log(`err: ${err}`);
      })
  }

  saveButtonHandler(){
    console.log('saveButtonHandler')
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
          <Navbar.Header>
            <Navbar.Brand>
              <a href="#">BIZIT</a>
            </Navbar.Brand>
          </Navbar.Header>
          <Navbar.Collapse>
            <Nav>
              <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Filter</NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Search</NavItem>
            </Nav>
            <Nav pullRight>
              <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#">Sign Up</NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Login</NavItem>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
        <CardList
          saveButtonHandler={this.saveButtonHandler}
          cards={this.state.cards}
          />
        <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect fixedBottom>
          <Navbar.Collapse>
            <Nav>
              <NavItem eventKey={4} href="#">Home</NavItem>
              <NavItem eventKey={5} href="#">Profile</NavItem>
              <LinkContainer to="/AddNewCard">
                <NavItem eventKey={6}>Add Card</NavItem>
              </LinkContainer>
              <NavItem eventKey={7} href="#">Saved Cards</NavItem>
            </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

App.propTypes = propTypes;
export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I just faced the same problem here. Yes you do have to set up react-router  as if you were not using react-router-bootstrap. For your application (guessing you just want same level paths with the NavItens u set) I think it will be something like this (assuming that you're rendering your app's component in a div with id="app"):

```
ReactDOM.render((
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home} />
        <Route path="/Filter" component={Filter} />
        <Route path="/Signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route path="/Login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/Profile" component={Profile} />
        <Route path="/Search" component={Search} />
        <Route path="/AddNewCard" component={AddNewCard} />
        <Route path="/SavedCard" component={SavedCard} /> 
   </Route>
</Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

You have to put react-bootstrap's NavItens inside react-router-bootstrap's LinkContainers. If you have an index link you should use IndexLinkContainers instead. But if you want a link in your Navbar.Brand(which is your case), the best solution I found was to replace the Navbar.Brand for a react-router Link with className='nav-bar-brand'.

This is how I guess your solution should be:

```
<Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
      <Navbar.Header>
        <Link to='#' className='navbar-brand'>BIZIT</Link>
      </Navbar.Header>
      <Navbar.Collapse>
        <Nav>
          <LinkContainer to="Filter">
              <NavItem eventKey={1}>Filter</NavItem>
          </LinkContainer>
          <LinkContainer to="Search">
              <NavItem eventKey={2}>Search</NavItem>
          </LinkContainer>
        </Nav>
        <Nav pullRight>
          <LinkContainer to="/Signup">
              <NavItem eventKey={1}>Sign Up</NavItem>
          </LinkContainer>
          <LinkContainer to="/Login">
              <NavItem eventKey={2}>Login</NavItem>
          </LinkContainer>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
    <CardList
      saveButtonHandler={this.saveButtonHandler}
      cards={this.state.cards}
      />
    <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect fixedBottom>
      <Navbar.Collapse>
        <Nav>
          <LinkContainer to="/">
              <NavItem eventKey={4}>Home</NavItem>
          </LinkContainer>
          <LinkContainer to="/Profile">
              <NavItem eventKey={5}>Profile</NavItem>
          </LinkContainer>
          <LinkContainer to="/AddNewCard">
            <NavItem eventKey={6}>Add Card</NavItem>
          </LinkContainer>
          <LinkContainer to="/SavedCard">
              <NavItem eventKey={7}>Saved Cards</NavItem>
          </LinkContainer>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need react-router-bootstrap, you may use

```
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
...
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Navigation />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/path" element={<Path_Function />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

While inside navigation

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Container, Nav, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Outlet, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
...
   <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/path">Path Name</Nav.Link>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that every Link including NavLinks and LinksContainers must be a child to Router component. My problem was in placing the nav outside the router as a standalone component.